# How to to make absolute elements flow responsively?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position, absolute

I positioned these images as absolute with left/top as percentages.

[image]

But as I shrink the browser width the images start to overlap.I haven't set the position of the 3rd and 4th row yet, but as you can see they're overlapping each other.
[image]

I'm guessing that it's because of the set % distance of the images? How do I go about positioning the images so that they keep the same formation as the browser width decreases?

My container is set to Relative block, images as Absolute with % width and px height.

I got the idea from this design http://builtbybuffalo.com/  but I have no idea how they did it.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed but on their page the hexagons don't resize at all (well.. only on mobile view become rectangles...)

Comment: Sure it does, it has a few breakpoints.  The relevant one is at `max-width: 1180px`

Comment: @m1. No. They don't resize. take a ruler place it on the screen and see for yourself. All those hexagon do is nothing but what all inline-block element would do: if no space available they float beneath.

Comment: Are they inline? I thought they were absolute positioned. I don't see how they can float next to each other when the top/bottoms of the images would collide.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you! Negative margins work fine. I just have to add media queries now.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan true. Sorry, misread your comment.

Answer (score 0):

They way they did it is with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).
Basically they set a breakpoint when the content begins to look bad and added extra CSS to make the necessary adjustments.

You can see this in their css [here](http://builtbybuffalo.com/assets/css/screen.css?12f9870de7e891d441f21ae8e662595ff59aee7b).  Search for this string in that file: `@media screen and (max-width: 1180px)` and check out the CSS underneath it (you should format the CSS, since it's minified, you can do that using Chrome Dev Tools or something like [this](http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/)).

Comment: I see a lot of width changes. Is the the width of the containers? And I don't see top/right/bottom/left changes - does that mean the images are not positioned absolute? I know they use media queries, but I'm curious to how the images are positioned.

Comment: What I mean is as soon as I shrink the browser width the images begin to overlap.